# Debugging GWT remote

Tags: debugging, gwt, intellij-idea

I know there is a question about this:
[Is it possible to debug GWT client code on a REMOTE server using IntelliJ 9 Community Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629297/is-it-possible-to-debug-gwt-client-code-on-a-remote-server-using-intellij-9-comm)

Im struggling on this one too. Everything works as he explained it. But when I "Launch Default Browser" in the Development Mode I get the following Exception.

[TRACE] Finding entry point classes
[ERROR] Unable to find type 'de.factorplus.retail.artgui.client.app.main.MainViewImpl'

Could someone explain the parameters more in detail?

-noserver -war "[full path to your exploded war]" -gen "[full path to generated files]" -logLevel INFO -port [remote server port] -startupUrl "[URL of the remote page]" [com.company.YourEntryPoint]

I have it like:

- noserver
- war "C:...*workspace*\*project-name*\target\Project-Version-SNAPSHOT" (the zip as dir)
- gen "C:...*workspace*\*project-name*\target\classes"
- logLevel INFO
- port 8765
- startupUrl "http://server:8765/PROJECT/PROJECT.html" packages.PROJECT

and I use the classpath of the project.

It seems like it misses the sources on the server? OR am I wrong?

Is there already a better way to do this. Or do you see a mistake?

Hope you can help me.