# Debug a remote JBoss's GWT App in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gwt

It works to debug Java code running on a remote JBoss server on Linus, Eclipse runs on Windows. The code is can be traced with Eclipse's debugger and JDT. The ear is maven built.
Now I try to debug also the GWT Java code with Eclipse remote debug. Do I understand right, that this should be possible with com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode ? I do not want to use Superdev and Javascript, I very much prefer to debug Java in the Eclipse Debugger.
Has anybody tried this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use GWT 2.7, the DevMode is deprecsted and should no longer be used.

The debug way is the SuperDev Mode, you debug with the browsers builtin javascript debugger and a sourcemap that translates to the cirrent java line. The jboss is out of scope here, because everything happens in your browser.

Excellent support for sourcemaps is in chrome.

Comment: Thanks, I got SuperDev Mode to work. Sourcemaps show the Java source, but not Java variables, these are in Javascript. 
`String pwd` becomes

`pwd_1_g$: "xx"`


If you cannot use the Eclipse or Idea Java debugger, one of the biggest advantages of GWT is gone.
So, even if it is deprecated, I'd like to have the old dev mode work in my scenario.

Comment: There I can't help you :-) I can only tell you that sdm is far faster and the debugger is more expressive, even if you first think it is not. In the end the problem appears in js, not in java.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the help of this: [Is it possible to debug GWT client code on a REMOTE server using IntelliJ 9 Community Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629297/is-it-possible-to-debug-gwt-client-code-on-a-remote-server-using-intellij-9-comm/2633669#2633669)

Chrome 41 as browser with GWT Developer Plugin,
URL for the appp is http://linux:8080/myapp/?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

add -nosuperDevMode to the launch config,
add javaee.jar from Glassfish 4.1 to the top of its classpath